# Java - Reference primitive data-type?

Tags: java, reference

I know that with the following, a reference is made

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Integer value;
}

public class Main
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    MyClass john = new MyClass();
    john.value = 10;
    MyClass bob = john;
    bob.value = 20;

    System.out.println(Integer.toString(john.value));  // Should print value of "20"
  }
}
```

But how do you do similar referencing with primitive data-types?

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    Integer x = 30;
    Integer y = x;
    y = 40;
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(x));  // Prints "30". I want it to print "40"
  }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: you don't. Primitive values are always passed by value (i.e. they are copied).

Wrapper objects like `Integer` are also immutable, i.e. `y = 40` will create a new `Integer` object with the value 40 and assign it to `y`.

To achieve what you want you need a container object whose value you can change.

You could, for example, use `AtomicInteger`:

```
AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(30);
AtomicInteger y = x;
y.set( 40 );

System.out.println(x.get());
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. While `Integer` is not a primitive datatype but a wrapper class around the `int` primitive type, your code is equivalent to:

```
Integer y = x;
y = new Integer(40);
```

So you are actually changing the object `y` points to. This mechanism is called *auto-boxing*. There's a simple rule of thumb: in order to change the state of an object, rather than to replace the whole object, you have to call one of your object's methods. It's quite common for classes representing *values*, such as numbers, not to provide such methods, but to require that the object be replaced by a new one representing the new value.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your second code block is that `30` gets boxed into an Integer and assigned to `x`. Then you assign that same Integer to `y`. x and y are now pointing to the same object. But when you do `y = 40`, that 40 is boxed into a new Integer object and gets assigned to y. The Integer class is immutable, you won't be able to change its value after creation.